# Get z value for a point of polygon using JTS library?

Tags: 3d, geotools, jts-topology-suite

I have a polygon described with coordinates which have z value.

Is there any JTS utility that would allow me to get **Z value for a coordinate which is inside the polygon**?

I have a function for doing it.

Does it look reasonable?

```
private def getMinMaxEvelation(geometryWithZ:Geometry, someTwoDimGeometry: Geometry) = {
    val builder = new ConformingDelaunayTriangulationBuilder()
    builder.setSites(geometryWithZ)

    val zValues = someTwoDimGeometry.getCoordinates.toList.map{ coord =>
      builder.getSubdivision.locate(coord).dest().getZ
    }
    Elevation(minZ = zValues.min.toInt, maxZ = zValues.max.toInt)

  }
```

Comment: If you want to get the min and max elevation of a 2D geometry inside a 3D geometry, your code seems correct.

Comment: true, I want to get the min and max elevation of a 2D geometry inside a 3D geometry. Thank you!

Comment: Sergey, add your own answer to the question and marked it as accepted. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet. People say it's good!

```
private def getMinMaxEvelation(geometryWithZ:Geometry, someTwoDimGeometry: Geometry) = {
    val builder = new ConformingDelaunayTriangulationBuilder()
    builder.setSites(geometryWithZ)

    val zValues = someTwoDimGeometry.getCoordinates.toList.map{ coord =>
      builder.getSubdivision.locate(coord).dest().getZ
    }
    Elevation(minZ = zValues.min.toInt, maxZ = zValues.max.toInt)
}
```